# declaring a variable as constant after a certain time- what's the workaround

Tags: java, android

The situation is coded as following:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


import android.os.Bundle;

import com.makeIT.www.R;

public class MainScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /*final*/static Toolbar app_toolbar = null; //would like to declare constant here but,

    private Toolbar return_toolbar(){

        return findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activityscreen_main);
        app_toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);/*findViewById isn't available till here*/
```

So, I'd like to make the view `static final`, but as you can see `findViewById` isn't available until the layout is set. Hence, I can only make it `static`. (In this case, not making final wouldn't hurt but still if there's a workaround, I'd like to know it.)

**EDIT**:what I wanted to do here was to make app_toolbar available as static(i.e. without any instance association) but also as a constant, but you see for both to happen app_toobar should be defined in the class and not in one of the methods. One way would be to manually invoke the `onCreate` (if it was possible at all) but again the `Bundle` would not be availble to us. Is `overloading` the `onCreate` possible? If yes, how do we fetch the `Bundle` since we might wanna save the state

Comment: If the layout is still unset, then it would make sense to return `null`. Perhaps you can try and give some more context as to what/why you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @npinti , what I wanted to do here was to make app_toolbar available as static(i.e. without any instance association) but also as a constant, but you see for both to happen app_toobar should be defined in the class and not in one of the methods. So, I wanted to know if any workarounds were available to achieve this.

Comment: @npinti , more information added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are asking if it is possible to change a `final` variable.

Answer: it depends.

- If the `final` is a compile time constant, then no.  There is no practical way to do it.  The constant's will be inlined by the bytecode compiler and changing the field containing the constant will have no effect ... except on *other* code that accesses the field reflectively.
- If the `final` is not a compile time constant, then you cannot do it in Pure Java.  However, you can use reflection to alter the modifier flags on trhe `Field` object for a `final` variable and then change the variable's value.

However modifying a `final` field via reflection is unsafe.  An Java JIT or AOT compiler may emit native code that assumes that the value of a `final` does not change.  If you change the value via reflection, the changed value *may not be visible*.  Furthermore, this *may not* be something that can be fixed via the memory model; e.g. by adding actions with *happens before* relations.

Modification of `final` variables discussed explicitly in the Java language spec; see [JLS 17.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3).

My recommendation: don't do it.  Figure out another solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java related actually, not Android.

If a variable is declared as final, you have to assign a value to it at declaration and you cannot change the value. However, you can edit the properties of the object assigned to it.

you can make it `private static`, and make only a `public static` getter that returns the reference of the static value, so you can only get it from outside but assign it only from the class (MainScreenActivity) itself.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I was aware of the property of constants in java. What I wanted was a technique to circumvent the issue. Please see the EDIT part of my question

Comment: @juztcode, this is not an issue. This is what the language specification says. IMHO, the issue is that you are trying to take a wrong approach! :)

Comment: @RahulShukla , I didn't mean issue with the language, I meant my issue. :-) But, I actually don't know the approach to take, and hence the question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is what you are after, so I am going to state the following assumption: What you want is to be able to access the toolbar as a static variable, regardless of the state of the activity to which it belongs.

What I would do, would be to create a factory class whose aim is to create the toolbar. This would entail, however, that you make changes such that:

1. You get the toolbar by invoking the factory (which can be static if you like). You can wire up the factory to return a toolbar set up however you would like.
2. In the activity, you remove any code used to construct the toolbar (this would need to be moved to the factory class explained in 1) and then, simply call the factory from your activity.

The drawback with this approach, however is that:

1. You might need to use some extra logic to check if the component is rendered.
2. It will not be possible to access the object's parent (might not be a deal breaker, but sometimes you might need to access the parent container), at least not through the factory itself.

EDIT:
I haven't done Java in quite a while (and haven't touched Android in ages but...) what I meant was something like this:

```
public class ToolbarFactory {
    public static Toolbar getToolbar() {
        // In here you build your toolbar. You could move the existing code within your application which at the moment is building the toolbar.
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to get the toolbar, you can just do: `ToolbarFactory.getToolbar()` and this will give you the toolbar you are after.

Then, in your activity, I am assuming that you have something like so (pseudo code below):

```
Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
t.setThis(this);
s.setThat(that);
someContainer.add(t);
```

**The chunk above would need to be moved to the factory class and replaced by the following:**

```
someContainer.add(ToolbarFactory.getToolbar());
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how it might work, but I appreciate the help, thank you very much. Did  you read my EDIT in the question, I've tried to clarify the behaviour I wanted. I also mentioned a possible solution but don't know how to grab the Bundle.

Comment: @juztcode: I have updated my answer. If things are still unclear you can check up on the factory design pattern.